# Setted environmental variable for kotlin visible on admin but not on user account

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

I have kotlinc on my desktop with path:

```
C:\Users\tom\Desktop\kotlinc
```

Then in command line I check version of compiler:

```
C:\Users\tom\Desktop\kotlinc\bin>kotlinc -version
```

and this works (wanted to be sure about that).

I would like to modify PATH variable. I tried couple versions, but this is the current one:

I add new variable KOTLIN_HOME, I set its value to C:Users\tom\Desktop\kotlinc, then I edit PATH. It is Windows 10 so I just add new line %KOTLIN_HOME%\bin (I also tried just add to existing line). There is semicolon at the end of each line.

kotlinc -version used from C:\Users\tom doesn't work:

> 'kotlinc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

What to check first?

KOTLIN_HOME:

```
C:\Users\tom\Desktop\kotlinc
```

PATH:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
%KOTLIN_HOME%\bin;
```

Edit: variable is set on user account and doesn't work, after I relog on admin it start to work. Can anything be blocked?

This PATH also doesn't work:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\tom\Desktop\kotlinc\bin
```

Edit1: I launched command line with administrator rights and then environmental variable works.

Edit2: I changed post title

Comment: Use the real path in that `%path%` variable isntead of `%kotlin_home%`.

Comment: Updated my post.